# Unsigned character prints it's ascii value

Tags: c++, utf-8, char, cout, unsigned

I have C++ program that reads from a binary file *byte by byte* then outputs it as a character to the console.

After using `unsigned char` as a type, the console will print it's ascii value, which I didn't expect.

How do I get it to print the character instead of it's ascii value?

The reproducible code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char a;
    a = 'A';
    cout << (a > 31 ? a : '.');
 }
```

Comment: It should print the character. Please post a [mcve]. (And make sure that it is a printable character.)

Comment: It should print a character and I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/X7QDXN)

Comment: Do you know how to use `static_cast`?

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JsXbLRbjK9BAdKAK (uses promotion to `int`).

Comment: Maybe the problem is where you say 'something like this'. Please post accurate and complete code.

Comment: Maybe `some_char[i]` has value `'1'` and he thinks it is `1`?

Comment: I'll edit the question, please wait

Comment: So the question now is what characters are you expecting for values > 127? The obvious thing to try is just a static_cast to wchar_t, but it might not give you the characters you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest problem is caused by the mix of types in the conditional expression.

```
unsigned char a;
...
cout << (a > 31 ? a : '.');
```

This expression has type int because neither char type is big enough to include all the values of the other. (Apologies if the previous statement isn't totally accurate, I can't be bothered to read the fine print.)

Simply cast one char so that both result types for the conditional expression are the same, e.g. `a > 31 ? a : (unsigned char)'.'`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant cast it to char like instead of using **cout << (a > 31 ? a : '.');** you can just print cout << **(char)(a > 31 ? a : '.');** .